# Accessing Row from Previous Day in Pandas Dataframe with Apply

Tags: pandas

Im new to pandas and am trying to run a calculation on every row that uses the closing price from **yesterday** and prices from **today**. ie:

```
for 2011-07-26:
    new_column = max(df.high['2011-07-25'], df.close['2011-07-26'])
```

I thought about using iterating through all the rows, but thought it would be more efficient to use df.apply function. But, I cannot figure out how to access the previous days closing price from within my function.

Here is a snippet of my dataframe.

```
              open    high     low   close
date                                      
2011-07-22  1597.6  1607.7  1597.5  1601.5
2011-07-25  1618.2  1620.3  1609.4  1612.2
2011-07-26  1610.7  1617.5  1608.0  1616.8
```

whats the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) first:

```
In [8]: df['yesterday_high'] = df['high'].shift()

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
              open    high     low   close  yesterday_high
date                                                      
2011-07-22  1597.6  1607.7  1597.5  1601.5             NaN
2011-07-25  1618.2  1620.3  1609.4  1612.2          1607.7
2011-07-26  1610.7  1617.5  1608.0  1616.8          1620.3
```

Then you can take the max of the yesterday_high and close columns:

```
In [11]: df[['yesterday_high', 'close']].max(axis=1)
Out[11]: 
date
2011-07-22    1601.5
2011-07-25    1612.2
2011-07-26    1620.3

In [12] df['new_col'] = df[['yesterday_high', 'close']].max(axis=1)
```

or alternatively:

```
In [13]: df.apply(lambda x: max(x['yesterday_high'], x['close']), axis=1)
Out[13]: 
date
2011-07-22    1601.5
2011-07-25    1612.2
2011-07-26    1620.3
```

Comment: but I wanted to take the max of  todays high to yesterdays close. It looks like this is just taking the max from today's high and close.

Comment: @CraigH Sorry about that, I've updated, is this what you're after?